# Not sure if i am getting a bad reference

Tags: termination

I worked at a company for 6 years.  Relations with my 3 bosses was strained for the most part - they were miserable egomaniacs.  Finally I put in a grievance for harrassment and was subsequently dismisssed after an investigation by HR.

I went to court with an unfair dismissal and harrassment case. Although the unfair dismissal case was upheld, the harrassment was not, so I lost and ended up paying the company £5,000.  It has now been 3 years since then and I have been unable to get a permanent job.  I have had some great interviews and know the job could have been mine, but in the end I lose out with them saying I am not experienced enough - which is rubbish.  Some times I have been called back for up to 3 interviews for the same position, but when they make their decision, it is not in my favour.  I have now been unemployed for almost 2 years and only get the odd temp job, but then the agency stops calling too. I strongly suspect I am getting bad references from my ex company, but what can I do. It is ruining my life.  Please help.

Mary

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: Why are you still listing that company as your reference? Isn't it sort of obvious that they would bad mouth you? As you said, you've had temp jobs. Find someone else to act as your reference ...

Comment: Something is not right, here.  If the temp agency hired you at all, they're beyond the point of querying your references.  There is another variable here.  Also - you can have someone pose as an HR rep calling them for a reference, and see what they say.

Answer (score 4):

### Have you considered other factors?

It seems unlikely to me that the problem you describe is caused by a bad reference.  Is it possible that you are not putting the best foot forward on these temp jobs?  You should consider what things you might be doing to make a bad impression and try to adjust accordingly.